# How to set height for the container bar of JQuery Chosen plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-chosen

I was wondering is there any ways of setting the height of the bar itself for the drop down bar created by the JQuery Chosen plugin.

[image]

This is how the dropdown is created in my code:

```
@html.DropDownList("AllNames",null,string.Empty,new{@id="namesList"})

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () { 
        $("#namesList").chosen();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: if you want to change the height of the bar only then you can override their css by using `.chosen-single{ height: 100px; }`. But I don't see the point why you want to do this.